# how to resolve this svn tree conflict?

Tags: svn, tree-conflict

Here is some information about this tree conflict:

> The last update operation tried to delete/move/rename the directory >'models',but the directory was already edited
>
> Conflict Sources:
>
> Source Left:   http://.../svn/.../models@23800
>
> Source Right:  http://.../svn/.../models@23805

svn  status :

```
    $ svn status
    ...
    ?       logs\log-2016-05-14.php
    A  +  C models
    >   local dir edit, incoming dir delete or move upon update
    !       models\xxxModel.php
    M  +    models\xxxyyyModel.php
    !       models\defined
    !       models\defined\file1.php
    !       models\defined\file2.php
    Summary of conflicts:
    Tree conflicts: 1
```

I want to  retain server version and discard  all change from local.

update:

```
$svn resolve --accept=theirs-full models
svn: warning: W155027: Tree conflict can only be resolved to 'working' state; 'C:\wamp64\www\workapp\...\models' not resolved 
svn： E155027： Failure occurred resolving  one   or more  conflicts
```

If i use "svn resolve --accept working models" , will svn  choose local version?

How should I do?

Comment: `svn resolve --accept=theirs-full PATH`, based on http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.tour.cycle.html#svn.tour.cycle.resolve

Comment: @IvanJovović , i have tried it ,but have a failure.

Comment: failure of what kind? Can you paste what exactly you have tried and what was the outcome?

Comment: @IvanJovović, for  the operation I do, i have updated  question .